# Как сделать Web прилоежние с cocies

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как сделать приложение в Android Studio, что-бы это вебприложение хранило cocies в папке Android Data
Ещё мне нужно чтобы оно могло нормально работать, к примеру Spotify сайт чтобы нормально открывался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

открыть все сайты с гарантией вряд ли выйдет. Наверное там надо с заголовком юзер агента играться и вести бесконечную войну с программистами всех сайтов, которые пытаются отследить запуск сайта через WebView и запретить такой запуск. С куками же всё просто - это просто значение заголовка в ответе сервера и значение заголовка в запросе на сервер. Получите их, сохраните как угодно (в префы, например) и прикрепляйте к запросам в WebView.

А вообще - нет особого смысла такие приложения делать. Например, если не ошибаюсь, если вы не докажите случайному индийцу из ТП что они какой-то важный функционал имеют, то в магазин такое приложение просто не пустят.